# C# .net - || OR operator not behaving. Seems to be working as AND

Tags: c#, .net

This might just be me, but I've been trying to do a do...while loop in c# where the loop will end if either one of two conditions are true.

I'm using the || operator. Google tells me that that is OR, but my loop is only ending when both conditions are true.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is a code example:

```
int sugar=0, salt=0, value=0;
string tLine;

Console.WriteLine("Enter integer values to add to Sugar and Salt.");
Console.WriteLine("The loop should end when either one reaches 10 or more.");

do {
    Console.Write("Sugar? =");
    tLine = Console.ReadLine();
    int.TryParse(tLine, out value);
    sugar =sugar+value;
    Console.Write("Salt? =");
    tLine = Console.ReadLine();
    int.TryParse(tLine, out value);
    salt =salt+value;
    }while ((sugar<10) || (salt<10));

Console.WriteLine("Sugar={0}, Salt={1}", sugar, salt);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: If you mean __exclusive or__, use `^` instead of `||`.

Comment: The disparity between what you want and what actually happened is because you want the loop to END when sugar or salt is less than 10, but the code you write is that the loop CONTINUES while something something. So the expression you wrote is actually the complete opposite. If you want to negate a Boolean expression, you prefix it with  `!`, but since you did not really write in plaintext the exact conditions of when the loop should end, only that it involves two expressions, then I cannot tell you the right syntax.

Comment: The loop will *continue* while either condition is true.  The opposite of what you said.  Nothing that `!` can't fix.  Do consider the `break` statement instead, if often makes code easier to read.  Requires the lovely `for(;;) { }` statement.

Comment: This might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop is executed every time the condition is met. So you have to change it to:

```
while ((sugar<10) && (salt<10))
```

or

```
while (!((sugar>=10) || (salt>=10)));
```

Answer (score 7):

Since the condition in English is:

`"The loop should end when either one reaches 10 or more."`

Then the condition should be:

```
do
{
    ...
}
while (Sugar < 10 && Salt < 10);
```

You need to use '&&'. Then if either Salt or Sugar becomes >= 10, the result of the `&&` will be `false` and the loop will therefore terminate.

However, you can use `||` by inverting the result of the comparison, like so:

```
while (!(Sugar >= 10 || Salt >= 10))
```

But that's much harder to read.

Some languages have `until`, but C# doesn't. If it did, it would look like:

```
until (Sugar >= 10 || Salt >= 10)
```

In other words, `until (condition)` is really the same as `while (!condition)`.

Comment: Thank you.  I should have been using AND instead of OR. What a donut.

Answer (score 4):

Or you write

```
while ((sugar<10) && (salt<10));
```

As long as both are below 10 the `while` goes on.

Comment: Or equivalently, but maybe easier to grasp, `while (!(sugar>=10 || salt>=10))` which means _until_ either sugar is at least ten or salt is at least ten. Boolean logic can be confusing, but see [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: For sure also possible :)